# My Instagram profile is public but my photos are posted as private

Tags: photos, instagram

For the last week now, every photo that I post can only be seen by people that follow me and not publicly - eventhough my profile is set as public. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this? I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: Have you turn off the private account setting?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your profile is actually private. If it actually is set to private (i.e only followers can see your posts), then when you try to look at your account while not logged in, or an a non-follower account, it will inform you that only followers can see your content. It will also have a 'requested' button when you try to follow. If you would like to supply your URL, we would happily check for you.

In order to check if it is private:

> 1. Go to your profile.
> 2. Go to your settings (gear icon usually).
> 3. Untick the 'Private Account' switch.

However, the way you're describing it (non-followers can access your account but not view photos) may be a symptom of shadowbanning. This is where Instagram silently bans your account and hides your content without telling you. It's a method of stopping malicious users from instantly creating a new account and breaking rules again, since they don't realise straight away.